# .net 4.8 install failing - the revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline

Tags: .net, windows-server-2016, .net-4.8

Server 2016 attempting to install the offline dotnet 4.8 exe "ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe" I receive the following error:

"the revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline"

Have attempted disabling Check for publisher's certificate revocation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the steps below:

Step 1:

- Run Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc)
- When the Local Group Policy Editor opens, expand Computer Configuration > Security Settings > Public Key Policies, and then double click on certificate path validation settings.
- When certificate path validation settings properties open, go to the network retrieval tab.
- check "Define these policy settings" and then uncheck "Automatically update certificates in the Microsoft root certificate program (recommended)".
- Click OK.
- note: This configuration change can impact the security of your deployment. Before proceeding, your organization should internally review and assess the impact of disabling this setting.

Step 2:

download these three CRL files using a pc that has access to the internet and copy them to your server.

[MicRooCerAut2011_2011_03_22.crl](http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/MicRooCerAut2011_2011_03_22.crl)

[MicCodSigPCA2011_2011-07-08.crl](http://www.microsoft.com/pkiops/crl/MicCodSigPCA2011_2011-07-08.crl)

[microsoftrootcert.crl](http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/crl/products/microsoftrootcert.crl)

I assume you copied the files to the root of drive D, Open PowerShell, and execute these commands:

```
certutil.exe -addstore -f Root D:\microsoftrootcert.crl
certutil.exe -addstore -f Root D:\MicCodSigPCA2011_2011-07-08.crl
certutil.exe -addstore -f Root D:\MicRooCerAut2011_2011_03_22.crl
```

Step 3:

Install .net 4.8 and as soon as installation completed revert the settings that you changed in step one.

**Do not forget to reset the settings of step one after installation.**